# How to store and retrieve file names in SQL Server 2014

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2014

I have uploaded 3 files i.e video, image and a word file. Now I want to store and retrieve it from database, eventually video name is saving in database but image name and word file name are not stored nor retrieving. What should I do?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSKU(SKU_Det skufiles, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        TraderCartMvcEntities db = new TraderCartMvcEntities();

        //UploadLogo(skufiles.File);
        var httpPostedFile = Request.Files[0];

        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            // Validate the uploaded file if you want like content length(optional)
            // Get the complete file path
            var uploadFilesDir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Videos");

            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFilesDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFilesDir);
            }

            var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(uploadFilesDir, httpPostedFile.FileName);
            httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Admin/Images/") + file.FileName);
                }
            }

            //if (file != null)
            //{
            //    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Admin/Images/")
            //                                          + file.FileName);
            //}

            SKU_Det sku = new SKU_Det();

            sku.SKU = skufiles.SKU;
            sku.VideoPath = httpPostedFile.FileName;
            sku.Imagepath = skufiles.SKU;
            sku.FilePath = skufiles.SKU;
            db.SKU_Det.Add(sku);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: I am guessing you are using `EntityFramework` based on `TraderCartMvcEntities`. 1. You should follow a tutorial on how to use EntityFramework so you know how to retrieve and persist data. Also how to wrap your usages of a DbContext in a using block so it gets disposed correctly. 2. Follow a tutorial on MVC so you know how to return data in a view using a Model. Then you can put 1 and 2 together and give this a shot by returning the image path as a part of your model and then adding that to an image tag. If you are also lost with HTML then I recommend you follow another tutorial on HTML.

Comment: reason being  skufiles.SKU is null

Comment: Thanks Marc_s and @coder771.
skufiles.SKU value is not null, its giving correct value but i thing i am making mistake in below code: 
sku.Imagepath = skufiles.SKU;
            sku.FilePath = skufiles.SKU;